# Trace kernel object calls

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, trace

We have `strace` to trace programs, `ltrace` for dynamic libraries, and others.

Is there any equivalent for kernel objects, as in tracing just like `strace` but for a specific `.ko`?

Thanks

Comment: google for ftrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Ftrace`. Ftrace is a tracing utility built directly into the Linux kernel. Checkout [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/365835/) for usage.